# Entity framework order by expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities, expression

I have encountered an issue with a ExtJS grid where I enabled remote filtering, sorting and grouping.

```
System.NotSupportedException: Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ValidateAndAdjustCastTypes(TypeUsage toType, TypeUsage fromType, Type toClrType, Type fromClrType)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.GetCastTargetType(TypeUsage fromType, Type toClrType, Type fromClrType, Boolean preserveCastForDateTime)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.CreateCastExpression(DbExpression source, Type toClrType, Type fromClrType)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ConvertTranslator.TranslateUnary(ExpressionConverter parent, UnaryExpression unary, DbExpression operand)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.UnaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, UnaryExpression linq)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
bij  System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding& binding)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.UnarySequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.UnarySequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SelectTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
bij Systm.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassc.<GetResultsAsync>b__a()
bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<ExecuteInTransactionAsync>d__3d`1.MoveNext()
```

The code sample below converts the input model (string properties indicating direction and property name) and generates a LINQ script on the fly, which will be used in the repository pattern, and consequently also Entity Framework. This script works well for non-nullable types, but it gives the error above when nullable properties are being sorted.

```
Expression<Func<Task, object>> orderByClause = default(Expression<Func<Task, object>>);
if (sortObjects != null)
{
       foreach (Order sortObject in sortObjects)
       {
        // Get type and property of type
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Task), "x");                       
        PropertyInfo property = typeof(Task).GetProperty(sortObject.Property);

         // Create left hand side of the lambda: x => x.PROPERTY
        MemberExpression propertyAccess = Expression.Property(parameter, property);
        LambdaExpression orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);

        // Create expression from lambda
        MemberExpression orderByExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, sortObject.Property);
        Expression conversion = Expression.Convert(orderByExpression, typeof(object));

        Expression<Func<Task,object>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Task, object>>(conversion, parameter);
        if (orderByClause == default(Expression<Func<Task, object>>))
       {
         orderByClause = lambda;
       }
       else
       {
          InvocationExpression invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(lambda, orderByClause.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
           orderByClause = Expression.Lambda<Func<Task, object>>(Expression.AndAlso(orderByClause.Body, invokedExpr), orderByClause.Parameters);
       }
      }
 }

  return orderByClause;
```

The issue here probably is the casting between the object and the nullable type. I'd need to be able to box the nullable type in the expression.

I was thinking of two options here:

1) Use some kind of generic method to define the property type instead of using the object type

2) Box the nullable property so it can be casted to an object.

I think option 2 is the easiest but I'm kind of stuck here.

**Update:**

I still haven't found a solution for this but I have a workaround until I have solved this issue. Now the sorting key isn't an object anymore, instead it's a generic type. This scenario will always work because there isn't any boxing occurring anymore:

```
 protected virtual Expression<Func<T, TKey>> GetSorting<TKey>(string ordering)
    {
        IEnumerable<Order> sortObjects = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ordering) ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Order>>(ordering);

        Expression<Func<T, TKey>> orderByClause = default(Expression<Func<T, TKey>>);
        if (sortObjects != null)
        {
            foreach (Order sortObject in sortObjects)
            {
                // Get type and property of type
                ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
                PropertyInfo property = typeof(T).GetProperty(sortObject.Property);

                // Create left hand side of the lambda: x => x.PROPERTY
                MemberExpression propertyAccess = !sortObject.ComplexType ? Expression.Property(parameter, property) : Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.Property(parameter, property), sortObject.ComplexTypeProperty);
                MemberExpression orderByExpression = !sortObject.ComplexType ? Expression.Property(parameter, sortObject.Property) : Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.Property(parameter, property), sortObject.ComplexTypeProperty);

                // Create expression from lambda
                Expression<Func<T, TKey>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TKey>>(orderByExpression, parameter);
                if (orderByClause == default(Expression<Func<T, TKey>>))
                {
                    orderByClause = lambda;
                }
                else
                {
                    InvocationExpression invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(lambda, orderByClause.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
                    orderByClause = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TKey>>(Expression.AndAlso(orderByClause.Body, invokedExpr), orderByClause.Parameters);
                }
            }
        }

        return orderByClause;
    }
```

Here's how I call this method. From the user's input, I determine which property is being sorted. Using reflection, I retrieve the its type, which I then pass as the type for the sorting method.

```
switch (propertyType)
  {
          case "Int32":
            Expression<Func<Resource, int?>> orderIntExpression = this.GetSorting<int?>(ordering);
            return await this.GetResources<int?>(page, pageSize, orderIntExpression, base.IsAscending(ordering), selector, mergedQuery);
           default:
              Expression<Func<Resource, object>> orderDefaultExpression = this.GetSorting<object>(ordering);
              return await this.GetResources<object>(page, pageSize, orderDefaultExpression, base.IsAscending(ordering), selector, mergedQuery);
  }
```

This works but it's not very scalable in my opinion. I don't see any easy or pretty fixes here to dynamically pass the type to the sorting method. Any suggestions on this matter?

Comment: Could you post a complete code to reproduce this problem?

Comment: I have updated my question with some new information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again after a lot of trial and error I have rescued myself by writing the code below. It is not complete yet but this allows sorting and grouping nullable types.

```
 Expression<Func<T, dynamic>> sortExpression = default(Expression<Func<T, dynamic>>);
 IEnumerable<Order> sortObjects = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ordering) ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Order>>(ordering);
 if (sortObjects != null)
 {
   foreach (Order sortObject in sortObjects)
   {
      Type type = typeof(T);
      ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
      MemberExpression propertyReference = Expression.Property(parameter, sortObject.Property);
      Expression conversion = Expression.Convert(propertyReference, typeof(object));
      sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, dynamic>>(conversion, new[] { parameter });

                break;
   }
}
return sortExpression;
```